# The "screen" tag: was once GNU Screen, now many other things

Tags: discussion, tags, taxonomy

Shortly after Stack Overflow came into the world, the [screen tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) was created and it referred to [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), the terminal multiplexing software.  These days, the screen tag is applied to all sorts of questions, many about [screen scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen%20screen-scraping), screen [resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen%20resolution) or [DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen%20dpi), and [screens on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen%20android).

How can we go about creating a new tag, gnu-screen, applying it to existing questions as appropriate, and encouraging its use for new questions?

Comment: More generally: we need to get tag wikis set up for as many tags as possible in this situation (occasional use, no 100+ upvote answerers) and we need to display a summary of the intended use from the wiki next to the tag editor for each tag selected so the asker knows they've got the right one. For the first, some sort of priv notification 'you can now create a tag wiki for tag X' for tags with empty wikis? Grant tag creator permission to edit the wiki for new tags?

Comment: Definitely a good point—a good tag wiki may have prevented this situation.

Answer (score 1):

There's "only" about 400 of these, of which it looks like fewer than half are really about gnu-screen anymore.  It sould be possible to take care of this yourself via edits over a couple days.

Comment: I did go ahead and re-tag most of them: I looked at questions that shared "screen" and some other terminal-like tag (terminal, vim, linux, etc.)